# Javascript element doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, slider

I am working on a webpage on Wordpress and I wanted to insert a slider with the posts from 6 blogs. The posts would be chosen by me, for that I am using Advanced Custom Fields plugin for that. The php part works properly, but I don't get the js working. Here is my html code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
<script>
$(window).load(function() {
    $(".flexslider").flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
    });
 });
</script>
```

Here is the html for the slider:

```
<div id="grey" class="row main-post">
<div class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <?php
    echo get_chosen_post();
    echo get_chosen_post_1();
    echo get_chosen_post_2();
    ?>
  </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

And one of the functions for retrieving the posts from the fields:

```
  function get_chosen_post() {
    global $wpdb;
    $post_title = get_field('post_title');
    $blog = get_field('blog_number');
    switch_to_blog( $blog );
    $posts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts WHERE post_type='post' AND post_status='publish' AND post_title LIKE '$post_title' LIMIT 1");
    foreach($posts as $post) {
        //Thumbnail
            $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'large' );
            $url = $thumb['0'];
        $html .= '<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mainpost "><div class="main-center"><a class="img-wrapper" href="'.get_permalink( $post->ID ).'"><img class="main-post-img" src="'.$url.'"></img></a></div></div>';

        $html .= '<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mainpost no-padding"><div class="main-center mobile-text-fix">';
        //Title
        $html .= '<h4><a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'" title="'.$post->post_title.'">'.$post->post_title.'</a></h4>';
        //Excerpt
        $html .= '<p>'.$post->post_excerpt.'</p>';
        $html .= '</div></div>';

    }
switch_to_blog(1);
return $html;
}
```

The query works fine, I use the LIKE statement to avoid errors if the post title contains quotes. My slider doesn't work, it just shows all the posts that I chose and the links to them, but no slider.
I would appreciate your help, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think slider not works because in html result there isn't **LI** element, but only *DIV*.
You can try

```
  <ul class="slides">
    <li>  <?php   echo get_chosen_post(); ?></li>
    <li> <?php   echo get_chosen_post_1(); ?></li>
    <li> <?php echo get_chosen_post_2(); ?></li>
  </ul>
```

or

```
foreach($posts as $post) {
    $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'large' );
    $url = $thumb['0'];
    $html .= '<li>';
    $html .= '<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mainpost "><div class="main-center"><a class="img-wrapper" href="'.get_permalink( $post->ID ).'"><img class="main-post-img" src="'.$url.'"></img></a></div></div>';

    $html .= '<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mainpost no-padding"><div class="main-center mobile-text-fix">';
    //Title
    $html .= '<h4><a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'" title="'.$post->post_title.'">'.$post->post_title.'</a></h4>';
    //Excerpt
    $html .= '<p>'.$post->post_excerpt.'</p>';
    $html .= '</div></div>';
    $html .= '</li>';
}
```

i hope this can help you